# how to generate crystal reports by custom query

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have following code to generate crystal report

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = DataUtility.GetDataSet("  SELECT * FROM donation ") 
        Dim objRpt As New t
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
```

Here getDataSet is a function to generate dataset. I also create a crystal report name t and show some field from donation table. It is fine. But i dont understant if i change as below

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = DataUtility.GetDataSet("  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM donation ")  
        Dim objRpt As New t
        objRpt.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
```

Now it have same result. But i think it should select only one row.
can anyone explane this?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be correct for your statement. What you can try is using  ROWCOUNT to see if it makes a difference:

```
("SET ROWCOUNT 1  SELECT * FROM donation ")
```

If you still get the same result as the original query, you may have to clear the dataset first. It could be that the old data gets retained somehow.
What you can do is to throw in a `Report.Refresh();` to refresh the report data.

EDIT:

Try this code:

```
Dim objRpt As New t
objRpt.SetDataSource("")
objRpt.Refresh()
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds = DataUtility.GetDataSet("  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM donation ")  
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
```

If that doesn't work at all, you might want to take a look at this [post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?489668-RESOLVED-How-to-programmatically-set-data-source-for-Crystal-Reports-basic-for-VS-2008), which describes in great detail how to programmatically set the datasource for a Crystal Report in vb.

Comment: it give same result, all records.

Comment: more then 20000 in crystal report. but how to check in dataset?

Comment: my process is currect? or i have to set something in crystal report?

Comment: in dataset ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count give me result one

Comment: So it sounds like your Crystal Report is not getting refreshed. Do you maybe have "Save Data with Report" checked? If not, set your datasource to null at the very beginning of your code to ensure the report has no data at the beginning.

Comment: i change my code  and add line objRpt.SetDataSource("") and now it give blank report. no results